# Общение между процессом-демоном и cli

Tags: c++, сокет, командная-строка, daemon

Есть процесс-демон и клиент с cli. Необходимо написать динамическую библиотеку для их общения, то есть клиент вводит команды, а процесс-демон на них отвечает.

Как лучше всего это организовать, чтоб можно было использовать несколько клиентов? (вся реализация общения должна быть в библиотеке, так как планируется добавить web-интерфейс, то есть из демона я вызываю функцию create_server, из клиента - create_client)

Думаю использовать сокеты, но не могу придумать, как это реализовать.

Comment: Делал подобное на shm_open. Сокет хорош, но, только если демон и клиент находятся на разных машинах. Локально можно обойтись пайпом или shm-ом.

Comment: конечно сокеты... трубы и разделяемая память тут абсолютно ни к чему... в рамках POSIX есть ещё вариант очередь сообщений сделать, но 99%, что оно не нужно... по поводу как — скорей всего ответа не будет, вопрос слишком общий... все детали работы с сокетами в одном ответе не опишешь или уточни вопрос, или начинай так, а по ходу дела задавай вопросы по поводу более  мелких и конкретных проблем...

Comment: @test123 спасибо

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а мне точного ответа и не надо, просто думал, что использовать. Спасибо